# Are the statistical words contrasts and post hoc synonymous?

Tags: mixed-model, multiple-comparisons, post-hoc, contrasts

I have implemented a linear mixed-effects model using `lmer{}` model in `R` and used `glht` to to preform a multiple comparison set of Tukey test.

What is the proper way to report these multiple comparison post tests:

1. Are they `multiple-comparison Tukey contrasts`
2. Or maybe a `multiple-comparison Tukey post hoc test`?

I see the word contrasts in the documentation but not really familiar enough with the difference between contrasts and post-hoc tests to know what the difference is.

Are they synonymous?

Comment: To address the yes-or-no question in the title: "[contrast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contrast_(statistics))" is not synonymous with "[post hoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_hoc_analysis)"

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks for your comment.  Any chance they are part of a logical consistency that would say something like:  "All contrasts are post hoc tests but not all post hoc tests are contrasts?"

Comment: It's possible to test contrasts that are not post hoc (though it's probably relatively rare).

Comment: @Glen_b Thank you for your help.  By the definitions I understand, I am quite sure that I am retrieving the Tukey multiple comparisons in a manner that satisfies the definition of the words themselves `post hoc`.  In your opinion do you know if it would be wrong to refer to this as a post hoc test. i.e. is post hoc a more general term?  The people I am working with don't like the word contrasts, they think its not a well understood term and I should avoid it.  I am not so sure because `multcomp` documentation specifically calls them contrasts.

Comment: I don't think you would have any difficulty using the term '*post hoc*' (since you seem to be doing it post hoc) and avoiding the word 'contrast'.

Comment: The question is somewhat like asking if "car" and "road" are synonymous. A comparison of two means is a special case of a contrast. A contrast is a linear combination of means where the coefficients sum to zero, so a special case is when the coefficients are -1 and 1 with the rest zero. Post hoc tests are tests of all manner of hypotheses, possibly but not necessarily hypotheses about contrasts or comparisons, conducted after an initial model-fitting analysis such as ANOVA. The tests are *of* the contrasts, not the contrasts themselves.

Comment: @rvl Thanks for your comment.  In the reading I did since comments from @Glen_b I formed the impression that a contrast is a bounded or constrained type of post-hoc test.  But the last sentence of your comment was extremely helpful!  Thanks.  Really helped me understand a little better the difference between what the tests are testing.  I was assuming the two names of tests had to be similar because `Tukey` formulations have to be consistent in the underlying math.  Changing the data from the raw data to the model fit contrasts clears up a lot of my confusion.  Excellent.

Comment: There's also a `glht`-specific confusion here.  In `glht`, the term "tukey" is used to indicate the contrasts to be used.  That is "tukey contrasts" are all pairwise contrasts.  It doesn't indicate a Tukey test per se.

Answer (score 1):

Partially answered in comments:

> To address the yes-or-no question in the title: "[contrast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contrast_(statistics))" is not
>   synonymous with "post hoc"

– Glen_b

> A contrast is a linear combination of means where the coefficients sum to zero, so a special case is when the coefficients are -1 and 1 with the rest zero. Post hoc tests are tests of all manner of hypotheses, possibly but not necessarily hypotheses about contrasts or comparisons, conducted after an initial model-fitting analysis such as ANOVA. The tests are of the contrasts, not the contrasts themselves.

--rvl